# Integrity error on sumbit form in django?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

[image]I am new to django I am having a 8 rooms in the bootstrap cards and then a form to submit one user can select one room only so I wrote my models as the rooms model consisting of data and I get that data in html page rooms.html and it is working properly but on select that one card i.e the selected roomid should go as a value of hidden input in my form how should I achieve this?

```
class rooms(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')

class users(models.Model):
    email=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    password=models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
    room = models.ForeignKey(rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My form template

```
div class="card-body">
              <form action="{% url 'car:user_register' %}" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="room"></label>
                <input type="hidden" name="room" class="form-control" value="{{i.id}}" required>
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password2">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
            </form>
```

And in views.py

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        room = request.POST["room"]
        username=request.POST["username"]

        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = users( password=password,email=email)
        user.save()

        return render(request,'home.html')
```

Error is:IntegrityError at /car/user_register/

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: Ya @pedram can you please say how to get the previous page selected card or that room_id in the form as value for input hidden field ? and I included traceback.can you see please

Comment: Check the answer, the error occurs because you didn't provide any value for the **mandatory** `room` field in your `Users` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the value for the `room` foreign key before saving the user:

```
def user_register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        room = request.POST["room"]
        username=request.POST["username"]

        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = users( password=password,email=email)
        user.room_id = room  # <------
        user.save()

        return render(request,'home.html')
```

Comment: then this local variable 'user' referenced before assignment
is coming

Comment: can you please say this

Comment: Did you put the `user.room_id = room` line after the `user = users( password=password,email=email)`?

Comment: yes now the error changed as Cannot assign "u''": "users.room" must be a "rooms" instance.
 what does this mean?

Comment: Actually the room field is the foreign key of rooms table in the users table I didnt understand the error

Comment: I think you are setting `user.room` instead of `user.room_id`; use `user.room_id = room` or `user.room = rooms.objects.get(pk=room)`

Comment: Yes as you said i used the two ways even the error is same.

Comment: I used the second way you said and the error is                                                                   local variable 'room' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET

Comment: Why you are sending a `GET` request to your view (it supposed to only handle `POST` requests)? Make sure all the code in your view is indented enough to be included under `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: I had indented and the previous error cam as Cannot assign "u''": "users.room" must be a "rooms" instance.

Comment: Actually could you please say how to get the user selected ones details like id in the room field of users table i am not understanding

Comment: actually as you said i changed everything once again and error is invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204037/discussion-between-pedram-parsian-and-g-lakshmi).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create "id". Django automatically created id when any record is saved and it is primary key.

So I suggest you to remove id field from model.

```
class rooms(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='0000000')
```